# How can I get the Xpath for the PageRank on Amazon?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

When I search something on Amazon (in this example: "Jeans"), I get an overview of products. I want to scrape/get the sequence of the product rank.

To make this more clear, I attached a picture. I want to have the numbers back (1,2,3,4 etc.).

Is this doable? I was hoping for an Xpath, but I couldn't found anything relevant in the HTML.

[image]

Sorry, this is my first question. Hopefully everything make sense. I used Python in combination with Scrapy for this task.

EDIT.

I think that it is also possible to count some the 'div'. Anyone experience with that [see picture 2]. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E5kZY.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!   Please familiarize yourself with these FAQs and repost your question -- (1) How do I ask a good question - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask -- (2) How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example - https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: what are those products ranked by? Are they really "ranked" or are they just ordered. Are you saying you'd like the order of how they appear on the screen?

Comment: The items are currently listed in order of appearance on a specific page.   The sponsored items have a special flag.

Comment: Hello Guys, thanks for the feedback. Indeed chitown88, I want to have the order how they appear on the screen. As mentioned by Life is Complex, Sponsored items are of course first, but I want to know the rank of the rest. Amazing your help!

Answer (score 0):

For amazon I use this xpath

```
xpath_results= "//h5/a"
```

Its for the "main" text for products, if you know how to use xpath (xml tree and beautifulsoup) you will get a list. Then iterate and you will know the order.
Your question was about xpath, so there you got

Comment: Hey Wonka! Thanks for your reply. Is it possible to extend your answer with a short example? How you did it with or xml tree of beautifulsoup? Appreciated!!